# Why is the tomcat default thread pool size so large?

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat

I notice that default tomcat 7 thread pool size seems to be 200.

> But normal CPU seems have 16 cores.

So only 16 threads can be executed paralleld

> Why does tomcat use so much threads.

Comment: Your computer is likely currently running tens of dozens of processes/threads. I doubt it has more than 4 "real" execution streams and yet everything can "run at the same time". This is due to [scheduling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)) found in modern operating systems.

Comment: I don't know the internals, but those threads may just sit around at no cost (except foot print), and a subset of them (ideally equal to the core count) are executing. So 200 could mean they expect a good amount of blocking threads.

Comment: A traditional strategy is to allocate many threads which mostly do io work intermixed with little cpu work. If you look at this chart http://norvig.com/21-days.html#answers then sending a packet from US to Europe takes a huge number of cpu cycles. Most of the time is spent waiting on io to memory/disk/network so hundreds of threads can share the cores. Newer servers/frameworks use different thread pools for different work eg Play framework which is nonblocking  http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ThreadPools some of their thread pools use one thred per core as not io nor blocking

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For long years many single core computer have been around and were able to run functions in a "pseudo-parallel" mode, that said, you might have 16 threads running in real parallel mode and others running in pseudo parallel.

For more information look at this: [Parallel Computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_computing)

To answer your question, these threads are useful to process requests, a bunch of them will be used for attending http requests and others will be used on calling the application logic.

Comment: Do you mean that http request requires little cpu usage, so tomcat can use more thread to make cpu more 'busy'?

Comment: Processing is faster than network transfers, specially on the internet so there is a lot of IO time to use cpu that would be otherwise wasted.

Answer (score 5):

Among 200 threads, only 16 threads are running on 16-core machine. The logic of a typical web application is to perform some light computation and heavy  database queries. Among 200 threads, only a few are doing computation and most of them are waiting for responses from databases.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the real-life web applications use database for storing application data and hence tend to be disk-intensive. Too many threads accessing the disk concurrently can cause disk-thrashing. So limiting the number of threads does make sense on a web application with a database.